# Reporting BingAds Revenue through GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, bing

I need to be able to report revenue back to bingads using only the google tag manager (I don't have access the back end of their site).

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I'm completely lost, and Bingads doesn't have much in the form of customer service.

Comment: I don't think you're giving enough information for somebody to be able to help you. Please can you provide some more details? Are these ads on your site? How are you tracking them at the moment?

Comment: Currently we aren't tracking because we have no access to the site. We have only conversions, not the variable amount.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already reviewed the [help pages](http://help.bingads.microsoft.com/apex/index/3/en-us/n5012). Have you also seen the example steps for the Bing Ads UET Demo page here? http://bingadsuet.azurewebsites.net/GoogleTagManager.html

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up bing UET tag within GTM, check out this article an improved version of bing ads conversion tracking

http://marketlytics.com/blog/bing-ads-conversion-tracking-and-remarketing-with-google-tag-manager